Multiple keystore certificates in JBoss EAP 7 configuration
I have a request to use one more Keystore certificate in JBoss EAP 7 standalone.xml. At the moment i have
<system-properties>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.keyStore" value="<path to file >"/>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword" value="<path to password>"/>
</system-properties>

one defined like this, certificate is used to establish the connection to external domain on server startup, is there a way to have one more Keystore in properties? later this certificate is used in HttpUrlConnection which connects to domain, but i have to differentiate the connections based on the request and have to use different certificates
